# Sqlite second date is greater than first date

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

In my database I have patient records and in the table have column name `Registered_Date` in this `yyyy-mm-dd` format so when I execute query like

```
SELECT Patient_ID,First_Name,Middle_Name,Last_Name 
FROM Patient_Records 
WHERE Registered_Date BETWEEN '2019-01-25' AND '2018-10-01'
```

There is no result...

As you can see the first date is greater than the second date but there is no result, but if the first date is less than the second date it will result all the patient whose registered on the selected date.

Comment: So what is your problem? Everything seems to work normally.

Comment: but if i swap the date the result show up sir like " Select Patient_ID,First_Name,Middle_Name,Last_Name from Patient_Records where Registered_Date between '2018-10-01' and '2019-01-25' " the result show its like similar to date

Comment: You may try to use time part: WHERE Registered_Date BETWEEN '2018-10-01 23:59:59' AND '2019-01-25 00:00:00' This will give you more accurate result.

Comment: `x BETWEEN y AND z` is the same as `x >= y AND x <= z`. See the problem when `z < y`?

Answer (score 1):

Everything works as intended.

From [the SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) :

> The `BETWEEN` operator is logically equivalent to a pair of comparisons. `x BETWEEN y AND z` is equivalent to `x >= y AND x <=z`

So if the first date is greater than the second (ie `y > z`), the condition will always be evaluated as false, no matter what value (`x`) it is given.